# Why block can't capture self?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used a data object to store an array data and when the data load completes, I have a block callback. But the problem is that there are different instances in the two methods:

```
@implementation DWHomeData

- (instancetype)initWithDataLoadCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion 
    DWHomeData *data = [DWHomeData new];
    data.dwStatus = [@[] mutableCopy];
    _completion = [completion copy];
    [self loadStatusData];
    return data;//<DWHomeData: 0x7fb481546860>
}

- (void)loadStatusData {
    DWHomeParam *param = [DWHomeParam new];
    [DWHomeTool fetchHomeStatusWithParam:param success:^(NSArray *statusArr) {
        self.dwStatus = statusArr;//self address:<DWHomeData: 0x7fb481548b00>
        _completion(YES);
    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
}

@end
```

My callback is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _homeData = [[DWHomeData alloc] initWithDataLoadCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];//_homeData address:<DWHomeData: 0x7fb481546860>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are `alloc`ing it twice. The method `new` is just a wrapper for an `alloc` and an `init`.

So when you call `[[DWHomeData alloc] initWith...` you allocated memory for the first instance of `DWHomeData`.
Then, inside the `initWith...` method you are calling `new` which allocated memory for the second instance of `DWHomeData` and you return **that** second instance, but you call `loadStatusData` on the first instance.

The easiest solution would be to replace that `new` call with the standard:

```
self = [super init]; // no alloc

if (self) {
    // initialize properties and call methods
}

return self;
```

Or you can do how I like to do all the time:

```
+ (instancetype)dataWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion { // static method

    DWHomeData *data = [DWHomeData new]; // alloc needed

    if (data) {
        [data loadStatusData];
    }

    return data;
}
```

and then call it without allocating:

```
_homeData = [DWHomeData dataWithCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

so the `alloc` is wrapped inside the static init method and there is no need to call it outside.

Comment: Thank you,I rarely use new method.It's actually alloc and init.So I got it.

Comment: It's ok to use it, but you have to keep in mind what's happening behind.